# Angular 5 snack-bar Notifications

Tags: angular, notifications, angular-material, toast

I want to implement notifications messages like

```
"Success! Your Details Added"
"Warning! Something Went Wrong"
"Danger! You don't have access to this"
```

i am already using angular material in my application
can i use ['snack-bar'](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/example) for notification purpose?

i also found some related [toaster at npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular5-toaster)

Suggest me if there is an another way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

empower your application with a personalized touch by crafting a bespoke component to elegantly showcase your messages.

Alternatively, consider the brilliance of [SweetAlert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2), a feature-rich library offering an array of functionalities and events, providing unparalleled control over your notification experiences.

Answer (score 12):

I use this [ngx-toastr](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr),  [demo](https://scttcper.github.io/ngx-toastr/)

- Toast Component Injection without being passed ViewContainerRef
- No use of *ngFor. Fewer dirty checks and higher performance.
- AoT compilation and lazy loading compatible
- Component inheritance for custom toasts
- SystemJS/UMD rollup bundle
- Animations using Angular's Web Animations API (polyfill needed for
  older devices)
- Output toasts to an optional target directive

Comment: I use ngx-toastr too, really useful and looks great.

Answer (score 6):

Though you are using angular material so its better to use snack-bar of angular material.

If you want to look for other options then you can also use [**growl** of primeng](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/growl) or [**message** of primeng](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/messages)

You can also write custom code for showing this kind of message you want. But in that case you have to control externally a lot of things like position of that message, timing, dismissing etc

So the choice is absolutely yours.

Comment: Keep in mind that now Growl is deprecated and the new version is under the name Toast.

Answer (score 5):

For notifications you can use [angular2-notifications](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-notifications).

For toaster you can use [angular2-toaster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-toaster).